# Couldn't find a .sty file in the new LaTeX installation with kpsewhich

Tags: installing, texlive

I have installed the TeXLive 2012 version on `/usr/local`. Then I have installed the malayalam package and the `malayalam.sty` is in the correct place
(ie at `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/malayalam`)

But I cant use the file the termiinal gives the error message the package is not found

also `kpsewhich` command couldn't find the file.

Comment: Issue the command `texhash` or `mktexlsr` to update TEX’s ﬁlename database and check `kpsewhich malayalam.sty` at terminal

Comment: You should have installed the package in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/malayalam`, not in the main tree. Then you have to issue `sudo mktexlsr` to update the file name database.

Comment: @egreg Please make that an answer

Answer (score 3):

The correct location for installing TeX related files not included in the TeX Live distribution is under

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

so, in your case, you should create

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/malayalam
```

and copy `malayalam.sty` in the created directory. After that you have to refresh the file name database:

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

Why not saving the file in `/usr/local/texlive/2012`? Because when a new release of TeX Live is issued, you would have to chase the old distribution for the files you have added in the meantime. This isn't necessary if one uses the `texmf-local` tree.